# Selecting specific row from a sub query depending on lowest priority

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with Clients and their Insurance Providers.  There is a column called Priority that ranges from 1-8.  I want to be able to select the lowest priority insurance into my 'master table'  I have a query that provides Fees, Dates, Doctors etc. and I need a subquery that I can join to the Main query on Client_ID  The priority doesn't always start with 1. The Insurance Table is the Many side of the relationship

```
Row#     Client_id  Insurance_id  Priority  active?
1         333           A            1        Y
2         333           B            2        Y
3         333           C            1        N
4         222           D            6        Y
5         222           A            8        Y
6         444           C            4        Y
7         444           A            5        Y
8         444           B            6        Y
```

Answer should be

```
      Client_id  Insurance_id  Priority
         333           A            1 
         222           D            6
         444           C            4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the results I *think* you're asking for pretty easily utilizing SQL's `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
declare @tbl table 
(
    Id int identity,
    ClientId int,
    InsuranceId char(1),
    [Priority] int,
    Active bit
)

insert into @tbl (ClientId, InsuranceId, [Priority], Active)
values (1, 'A', 1, 1),
    (1, 'A', 2, 1),
    (1, 'B', 3, 1),
    (1, 'B', 4, 1),
    (1, 'C', 1, 1),
    (1, 'C', 2, 0),
    (2, 'C', 1, 1),
    (2, 'C', 2, 1)

select Id, ClientId, InsuranceId, [Priority]
from
(
    select Id, 
        ClientId, 
        InsuranceId, 
        [Priority], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId, InsuranceId ORDER BY [Priority] desc) as RowNum
    from @tbl 
    where Active = 1
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
```

Results:

```
(8 row(s) affected)
Id          ClientId    InsuranceId Priority
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2           1           A           2
4           1           B           4
5           1           C           1
8           2           C           2

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I need to review PARTITION and ROW NUMBER but I don't think this example answers my question.  I need the lowest priority where the policy is active.  In your example you only have 2 clients, I would want rows 1 and 7 as a result.  One priority per client.  thanks, I will review your answer some more.

Comment: After doing some research on ROW_NUMBER() I realized what was happening when you combined it with PARTITION and this does indeed solve my problem.  What confused me in your RESULTS table was the multiple CLIENTID rows.  I wanted only one row per client with the lowest priority.  Anyway, thanks this worked perfectly when i applied it to my actual data.

Comment: Okay, so could you mark this as the answer to your problem then? ;)